# Classic Asp Error with no error message

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

When I am looping through a record set displaying it on the page, as soon as it hits:

```
posLeft = Cstr((Cint(rs("stoneleft"))*0.31))
```

it stops reading the DB and all other    `rs("")`'s don't work.

Am I doing this wrong? The stoneleft field is a varchar it converts it to integer (the test record I tried it with was '100') then multiplies by 0.31 and then converts to a string so I can display it on the page.

Comment: It works when I comment out this line, and all others display just fine.

Comment: Does a blank field cause an issue? Not sure if a null or "" can be cint'd. It's been quite a while though. I would log that field prior to the troubled statement.

Comment: My guess is rs("stoneleft") is either null or not a number. The exception would break out of code at that point causing nothing else to execute e.g. no more rs("") would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, fairly common problem in cASP, its been around since pre 2000. This is a DB driver issue, specifically your provider. In your connection string, try to change to the below. If you cant, do what @stealthyninja suggests.

problem

```
driver={SQL Server};
```

try (instead of the above)

```
driver=SQLNCLI;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you have a null or empty value from the db.

Try this:

```
If Len(rs("stoneleft") & "") > 0 Then 
  posLeft = Cstr((Cint(rs("stoneleft"))*0.31))
End If
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
If IsNull(rs("stoneleft")) Or IsEmpty(rs("stoneleft")) Then 
  ' don't do stuff!
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

@Grant unwin: You should always assign row values to variables so you can get in the database to get your data then get out again before you start working with what you got out.

```
Dim stoneLeft, posLeft

stoneLeft = rs("stoneleft")

If NOT IsNumeric(stoneLeft) OR IsNull(stoneLeft) Then
    stoneLeft = 0
Else
    stoneLeft = CInt(stoneLeft)
End If

posLeft = stoneLeft * 0.31
```